# Play WS Standalone: Instantiating StandaloneAhcWSClient causes some wierd issues

Tags: scala, playframework, asynchttpclient

What I'm trying to accomplish is pretty much straight forward:

1. Instantiate a standalone instance as described [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-ws)
2. calling the remote service

However, if I run the test class I get this error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V at akka.util.Timeout.

You'll find the full stacktrace further below.

Any idea what could cause the issue and how to make the example work?

```
package restclient

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class RestClientTest extends WordSpecLike with ShouldMatchers {

  trait Fixture {
    val restClient = new RestClientImpl
  }

  "The Rest client" should {
    "" in new Fixture {
      val res = restClient.call("http://localhost:3000/post")
      res shouldBe "c"
    }
  }

}
```

=============================================

```
package restclient

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc._

// still WIP
trait RestClient {
  def call(url: String): String
}

class RestClientImpl extends RestClient {

  override def call(url: String): String = {

    // Create Akka system for thread and streaming management
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    system.registerOnTermination {
      System.exit(0)
    }
    implicit val m = ActorMaterializer()

    val wsClient = StandaloneAhcWSClient()
    "x"
  }

}
```

=============================================

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
    at akka.util.Timeout.(Timeout.scala:13)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.(ActorSystem.scala:327)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.(ActorSystem.scala:650)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:244)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:287)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:232)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:223)
    at 
restclient.RestClientImpl.call(RestClientImpl.scala:28)
    at 
restclient.RestClientTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anon$1.(RestClientTest.scala:16)
    at restclient.RestClientTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(RestClientTest.scala:15)
    at restclient.RestClientTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(RestClientTest.scala:15)
    at restclient.RestClientTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(RestClientTest.scala:15)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:953)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
    at restclient.RestClientTest.withFixture(RestClientTest.scala:8)
    at

=============================================

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-ahc-ws-standalone_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-ws-standalone-json_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What versions of Scala, Akka, and ScalaTest are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The project hasn't been updated for quite some time now and was still using Scala 2.11. But it turned out to be an unjustifiable hassle to update so I'm going to try out http4s.org.

Comment: Why not use _2.11 in that case?

Comment: Fair enough, but I was thinking if in the future Scala 2.13 should break again with 2.12 http4s could be somewhat easier to migrate.